# 19.10 Can't run on HP Pavilion 590-p0xxx

Tags: boot

Working with Ubuntu 19.10 from a USB drive that I have used to successfully install or run before on a Lenovo laptop and an iMac desktop.  I'm trying to set up dual boot on an HP Pavilion 590-p0xxx.

After the Power On Self Test completes and the choice to enter the BIOS/Firmware setup clears, the [GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) bootloader [(more detail)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) shows the choice to either run from USB or install.  Either way, I get the same result....screen goes blank, then I get the following:

> [   1.188909] [drm.drm_cal_timestamping_constants [drm]] *ERROR* crtc 66: Can't calculate constants, dotclock = 0!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are Fast Boot and Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  Secure boot is for sure.  Didn't see anything called "Fast Boot", but I do have "Legacy Boot" enabled.

Comment: As I mentioned above, whether I try to run it as a "try-out" from the USB drive OR attempt to install it from the USB drive, I get the same result, the message I quoted above.

Comment: !) When does the aforementioned error appear; immediately after selecting to Try or Install in GRUB2, or later on? If later on, after what? 2) Have you tried hold down the SHIFT key as the computer attempts to boot, to display the GRUB 2 menu, and then adding   _nomodeset_  after _quiet splash_ in the GRUB2 line which starts with _linux_?  (See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Editing_the_GRUB_2_Menu_During_Boot for how to.) 3) What happens if you run the memory test, instead?

Comment: It occurs immediately after I make the selection.  I haven't tried any of the other things you listed, but will at the next opportunity.